# Simulating the joint dynamics of a stock and an option

Tags: black-scholes, monte-carlo, probability, joint-probability

I want to know the joint dynamics of a stock and it's option for a finite number of moments between now and $T$ the expiration date of the option for a number of possible paths.

Let $r_{\mathrm{s}}$ and $r_{\mathrm{o}}$ denote the return on the stock and the option. Then I'm interested in knowing $\mathrm{E}_t([r_{\mathrm{s}}; r_{\mathrm{o}}])$ the expectation of the return from $t$ to $t+1$ and $\mathrm{Var}_t(r_{\mathrm{s}}, r_{\mathrm{o}})$ the variance from $t$ to $t+1$. The expected return and volatility of the stock are known.

My first idea is to use Monte Carlo with the following pseudocode:

```
N <- number of paths
T <- number of moments
M <- number of subpaths
S <- current stock price
for i = 1 to N:
    S_0 <- S
    for t = 0 to T-1:
        for j = 1 to M:
            S_{t+1,j} = f(S_t)
            O_{t+1,j} = BSM(S_{t,j})
        S_{t+1} <- mean(S_{t+1,j})
        E_{i,j} <- mean(S_{t+1,j}, O_{t+1,j})
        V_{i,j} <- var(S_{t+1,j}, O_{t+1,j})
return (E, V)
```

where $S_t$ is the current stock price, $f(S_t)$ gives a realization of stock price at the next moment given the current stock price, let's assume geometric Brownian Motion, $\textrm{BSM}(S_t)$ gives the option price given the current stock price and some arbitrary parameters using the BSM formula and `E` and `V` the values I'm interested in.

This can probably be optimized by a number of clever ideas such as reusing the draws from the probability distribution and discretizing the state space and use a memoized BSM. This is, however, not what I'm looking for. I rather calculate the mean and variance directly, the question is: how?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you assuming there exists an options pricing function _BSM(S,t,{params})_ or are options prices also supposed to come from the Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: I've updated the question, I assume the existence of the options pricing function $BSM(S,t,{params})$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this scenario, the "joint dynamics" are trivially computed since the option value is a known deterministic function of stock price.  For example, the mean of the option value for time $\tau$ is
$$
\mu_O = \int_0^\infty BSM( S_\tau ) p(S_\tau) dS_\tau
$$
which is best computed using [quadrature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LobattoQuadrature.html) as available in standard numerical libraries like [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html).  The function $p(S_\tau)$ would typically be the Black-Scholes probability density
$$
  \frac{n( d_2(S_0,S_\tau) )}  {S_\tau  \sigma \sqrt{\tau} }.
$$
with $S_\tau$ taking the place of strike $K$ in the formula for $d_2()$.

Similarly, the variance of the option value for time $\tau$ is
$$
\int_0^\infty (BSM( S_\tau ) - \mu_O)^2 p(S_\tau) dS_\tau
$$
and covariance of option value with stock price would be
$$
\int_0^\infty (BSM( S_\tau ) - \mu_O)(S_\tau-\mu_S) p(S_\tau) dS_\tau.
$$

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason for specifically referring to Lobatto Quadrature?

Comment: Not a big one -- I just thought I recalled the scipy version is Lobatto.

Comment: Fixed a couple errors in the original answer.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the $T - \tau$ and wondered whether it was correct under a different interpretation of the variables. Nice to know it's not ;) I've implemented most of it over the weekend and will show the result (appendix in my thesis) and MATLAB code soon, I hope. You've really been a great help, quadrature is new terrain for me and your answer was a great start.

Comment: how do you want to be credited in my thesis? Under Brian B or under some other name. If you want you can contact me via my profile.

Comment: How about Brian Boonstra, Illinois Institute of Technology.